# Yii2 Facebook login issue

Tags: php, facebook, yii2

I has tried to implement a facebook login in my website.I followed this method [tutorial](http://www.mushtaqtahir.com/blog/2/facebook-authentication-using-yii2-authclient). every thing is fine...but when I Run the website an error occurred **Class 'yiisoft\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found**
I am attaching my composer.json and view.php along with this
**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/authclient": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
},
```

and **my view**

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use app\models\User;
use vendor\yiisoft\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice;
     <?= yiisoft\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
     'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth']
]) ?>
```

and in **my web**

```
'authClientCollection' => [
      'class' => 'yiisoft\authclient\Collection',
      'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
          'class' => 'yiisoft\authclient\clients\Facebook',
          'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
          'clientId' => '************',
          'clientSecret' => '*********',
        ],
      ],
    ],
```

added these code..
Can anybody tell me why this is happening...

Comment: Extension installed using composer or directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget
```

Info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-widgets-authchoice.html

Comment: Yii classes are namespaced from yii\...\

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html

Answer (score 0):

composer.json 
in require section add this extension

```
 "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*"
```

first: frontend/config/main.php
need to paste

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
    'facebook' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
    'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
    'clientId' => '13232324242322424',
    'clientSecret' => '32jjkschsuc6dsgdjhsd7dtusdjsds7',
    'attributeNames' => ['name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
         ],
    ],

    ],
```

second:frontend/controller/sitecontroller
need to paste =======>>>

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
    'auth' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
    'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
         ],
    ];

}

public function oAuthSuccess($client) 
{
    $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    $user_email= $userAttributes['email'];
    $user_first_name = $userAttributes['first_name'];
    $user_last_name  = $userAttributes['last_name'];
    $model = new SignupForm();
    $user = $model->facebook_data($user_email,$user_last_name,$user_first_name);
    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

    exit;
    // do some thing with user data. for example with $userAttributes['email']
}
```

third step::
saving first_name,last_name in user table need to create additional attributes

```
public function facebook_data($user_email,$user_last_name,$user_first_name)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email= $user_email;
    $user->first_name =  $user_first_name;
    $user->last_name = $user_last_name;
    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
```

forth step:: 
from facebook developer site need to get app id and secrete key and paste in the first step where mention  'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
for localhost need to give url .
ex : my url is
http://localhost/noteshub/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin
i simply pasted in facebook website url while adding website to get 2 keys.

fifth step :
in view file need to paste this for facebook icon where you gonna click for...

```
 <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
                   'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth']
                  ]) ?>
```

its automatically viewed facebook icon in view file